# Can someone help me get Ubuntu touch on my Huawei Ascend y300?

Tags: installation, ubuntu-touch, phone, huawei

I have a Huawei Ascend Y300 which is the better big brother to the G300. I would like ubuntu touch installed on it, as it's the only device I have without Ubuntu.

It's a popular phone and I'm sure this would help many people out.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean **"Huawei Ascend G300"**?

If so you might want to check this out: → https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices/u8815 .

If you do mean the **"Y300"** it still may give you some insight...

Hope this helps... Good Luck!

Comment: I do still mean the y300, like I said, it's the bigger better brother of the G300.

Answer (score 0):

Like SocalldiegoRob said, the G300 might work, the specs are identical,except for a few tiny things such as the screen size and the space the user has available. As far as the important bits such as memory, cpu etc, they are all the same.
I also have a Y300 and want to try this, however, it seems that work on the port has stopped for some time, and I'm unsure whether it will continue. Either way, try the link that SocalldiegoRob gave.